# The interpreter says that n = list[0] is a list

Tags: python

I have to do a function that accepts an array, where the first element is the number of columns and rows of a matrix, the rest is the matrix itself. I have to return the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonals.

My problem is that the interpreter returns this traceback:

```
File "Solution.py", line 23, in diagonalDifference
    while counter != n + 1:
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

I don't why it intrepet '''n''' like a list, it's the first element of the'''lis''' list.

Here is the code

```
def diagonalDifference(arr):
    sumleftdiagonal = 0
    sumrightdiagonal = 0
    counter = 0
    lis = [i for i in arr]
    n = lis[0]
    lis.remove(lis[0])
    while counter != n + 1:
        sumleftdiagonal += lis[0 + counter]
        sumrightdiagonal += [n - counter]
        counter += 1
        for i in lis[:n+1]:
            lis.remove(i)

    return abs(sumleftdiagonal - sumrightdiagonal)
```

Comment: Try printing `lis` after assignment - I don't think it is what you think it is.

Comment: What is `arr`? Is it a list of lists perhaps?

Comment: I understand that it is an array. here is the input format: ```The first line contains a single integer, n, the number of rows and columns in the matrix arr.
Each of the next n lines describes a row, arr[i], and consists of n space-separated integers arr[i][j].```

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: Could you provide the contents of the first couple of elements in `arr` or `list`?

Comment: @Prune Yeah I tried to reduce the problem but when I do it everything goes right. So I don't know it has to be something in this code.

Comment: @Badgy ```arr = (3,
11, 2, 4,
4, 5, 6,
10, 8, -12)``` But is strange because in Pycharm it doens't show that Traceback, But in the Web interpreter it does

Comment: What is the web interpreter?

Comment: HackerRank's one. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem. That;s the problem, it says that ```arr``` is an array of integrers, but in the code (after the definition of the function) you can see ```arr = []```and that means that is a list. So I'm confused

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

**Your code does not work because** you are essentially evaluating the difference of the first row of the square matrix from itself.

```py
# this picks up members of first row (left to right)
sumleftdiagonal += lis[0 + counter]
# this picks up members of first row (right to left)
sumrightdiagonal += [n - counter]
counter += 1
```

You can verify that `sumleftdiagonal  = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `sumrightdiagonal = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` for the dummy data I used.

### Purely pythonic solution.

#### Method-1: `just python`

```py
# using the dummy data below: sum(diag_left - diag_right) = 0
n = arr[0]
sum([arr[1+n*i+i] - arr[1+(n-1)*(i+1)] for i in range(n)])
```

**Output**:

```sh
0
```

### Using `numpy`

If you can use `numpy` then there are at least two methods.

#### Method-2: using `numpy`

```py
import numpy as np

def diagdiff(arr):
    n, arr = arr[0], arr[1:]
    arr = np.array(arr).reshape((n,n))
    return sum(np.diag(arr) - np.diag(np.fliplr(arr)))

# Dummy Data
a = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5)) + 1
print(f'square-array: \n\n{a}\n')
arr = [int(np.sqrt(a.size))] + a.flatten().tolist()
dd = diagdiff(arr)
print(f'diagonal-difference: {dd}')
```

**Output**:

```sh
square-array:

[[ 1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10]
 [11 12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25]]

diagonal-difference: 0
```

#### Method-3: using `numpy`

```py
n, a = arr[0], np.array(arr[1:])
a = a.reshape((n,n))
sum([a[i, 0+i] - a[i, -(1+i)] for i in range(n)])
```

**Output**:

```sh
0
```

Comment: Thanks man. But want I need is to know why my code doesn't work

Comment: Take a look at it now. Added explanation why it is not working. I hope this helps. A word of advice: always pick a small example data and print out in a loop to see what is happening. It helps most of the time to weed out bugs early on.

Comment: @Thebigbosslong Please consider **`accepting`** and **`voting-up`** the solution if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```py
sumrightdiagonal += [n - counter]
```

On this line you are trying to append a list containing `n - counter`, I assume you mean `lis[n - counter]` here.

Comment: I tried your code, and the error in your post occurs on the line in my answer for me, rather than the while loop.

Comment: How is the traceback?

Comment: How is the traceback?

Comment: Same error, but on `sumrightdiagonal += [n - counter]`

Comment: What?... This is crazy